# Ввод текста в инпут

Tags: javascript, html

Не могу понять как это сделать, помогите пожалуйста
Ввод текста.
Дан инпут. В инпут непрерывно вводится произвольный текст максимум по 5 слов. Окончанием слова считается пробел. По достижении 5 слов строка из инпута переносится в абзац ниже, инпут очищается и ввод текста продолжается. В случае если в конце любого слова ставится точка, то ниже создается новый абзац и он начинает заполнятся тестом.
Каждое предложение автоматически начинается с заглавной буквы.

Comment: Вы с одной группы с автором [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1470929/508294) что ли?

Answer (score -2):

```
const input = document.getElementById('in');

input.oninput = function() {
   let array = input.value.split(/\s+/);
    if ((array.length == 5) || input.value[input.value.length-1] == '.') {
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = input.value;
    document.body.after(p);
    input.value = null;
  }
  
};
```